# Kaleidoscope Chapter 8 linker command failed with exit code 1143

Tags: visual-studio-2017, llvm, clang++, win64

I am new to LLVM and wanted to experiment with the Kaleidoscope example. My
PC is a Windows 64 bit system. I managed to build LLVM from source with
CMake. I managed to build the examples of Kaleidoscope with Visual Studio
15 2017 from the .vcxproj file. The built toy.exe from chapter 8 runs well
from the command line and I could enter the function definition for average
as in the tutorial. toy wrote output.o to D:\llvm.bld\Debug\bin.

However, when I would like to compile and link the main.cpp as given in the
tutorial I get:
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1143 (use -v to
see invocation).

The full verbose output is copied below. How do you compile and link
main.cpp and output.o on a Windows 64 bit PC?

Greetings,

Ad Huikeshoven

D:\llvm.bld\Debug\bin>clang++ main.cpp output.o -o main -v

clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: D:\LLVM\bin
 "D:\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.16.27025 -emit-obj -mrelax-all
-mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier
-discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic
-pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose
-mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info
-debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir
"D:\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.0" -internal-isystem
"D:\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.0\include" -internal-isystem
"D:\VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include"
-internal-isystem "D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt"
-internal-isystem "D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared"
-internal-isystem "D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um"
-internal-isystem "D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt"
-fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\llvm.bld\Debug\bin"
-ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions
-fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.16.27025 -std=c++14
-fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions
-fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o
"C:\Users\Ad\AppData\Local\Temp\main-884d07.o" -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 7.0.0 based upon LLVM 7.0.0 default target
x86_64-pc-win32
`#include "..." search starts here:`
`#include <...> search starts here:`
 D:\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.0\include
 D:\VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include
 D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
 D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared
 D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um
 D:\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt
End of search list.
 "D:\VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe"
-out:main -defaultlib:libcmt
"-libpath:D:\VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64"
"-libpath:D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64"
"-libpath:D:\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64" -nologo
"C:\Users\Ad\AppData\Local\Temp\main-884d07.o" output.o
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1143 (use -v to
see invocation)

Comment: How did you generate output.o from the toy? As the file format seems garbled (that's what the linker error 1143 is telling you), you either wrote the wrong object code to the file, or it became unreadable otherwise. Also, it might be easier to first compile into two object files (main.o, output.o) and link them in a second step, than instruct clang++ to compile-and-link

Comment: Also, it would help if you could clean up the log files, right now it is really hard to see where the commands end and the actual log begins.

Comment: Thanks @antipattern. The toy.cpp is described at https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl08.html. Toy is commandline interactive. I followed the example in the blog and entered a definition for an average function as in https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl08.html#putting-it-all-together. The program then writes output.o automatically. I copied the command from the blog.

Comment: I see. I presume you used MSVC to compile toy.cpp? Can you check which target triple is used within toy.cpp (what does the code in section 8.2 of the blog return?). Externally, the linker is using `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.16.27025`, this should match whatever is used in the toy to emit object code.

Comment: toy.cpp uses  auto TargetTriple = sys::getDefaultTargetTriple(); to get the TargetTriple. I added a line to print TargetTriple and got x86_64-pc-win32. I tried clang++ -target x86_64-pc-win32 main.cpp output.o -o main and got again "output.o : fatal error LNK1143: invalid or corrupt file: no symbol for COMDAT section 0x4
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1143 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Sorry about late reply. If this is still an issue, I find it weird that internally it is using the "...-win32" thing in the target triple, when externally, the linker path uses 64 bit libs which could explain the odd error message. I really suspect there is a mismatch between 32 and 64 bit. How is the kaleidoscope sample built, using win32/x86 or x64? Might be an idea to switch to 64bit built if that is not already the case.

Comment: @antipattern Some progress, I switched to a laptop with Ubuntu. Again I managed to compile LLVM from sources. Now the Kaleidoscope sample from Chapter8 compiles fine (as does the sample from Chapter3, all other Kaleidoscope sample don't compile). And, the output of toy.exe compiles and links fine with main.cpp using $ clang++ main.cpp output.o -o main -v. I will document the hurdles to compile LLVM elsewhere.